# C# How to replace a shorter string than the matched string?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

How can I replace only a part of a matched regex string ? I need to find some strings that are **inside** of some brackets like `< >`. In this example I need to match 23 characters and replace only 3 of them:

```
string input = "<tag abc=\"hello world\"> abc=\"whatever\"</tag>";
string output = Regex.Replace(result, ???, "def");
// wanted output: <tag def="hello world"> abc="whatever"</tag>
```

So I either need to find `abc` in `<tag abc="hello world">` or find `<tag abc="hello world">` and replace just `abc`. Do regular expressions or C# allow that ? And even if I solve the problem differently is it possible to match a big string but replace only a little part of it ?

Comment: Would something like `string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(<tag )(abc)(=\"")", "$1def$3");` suffice? However: xml/html is **not** "regular", and [you will go insane trying to solve generalised xml/html via regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454); please consider using a parser/dom instead

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, I'll keep that in mind. I will not go further than the little modifications I want to apply to the strings. I also know that my input strings will have a very low complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to look up the #NET regex dialect, but in general you want to capture the parts you don't want to replace and refer to them in your replacement string.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(<tag )abc(=\"hello world\">)", "$1def$2");
```

---

Another option would be to use lookaround to match `"abc"` where it follows `"<tag "` and precedes `"="hello world">"`

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=<tag )abc(?==\"hello world\")", "def");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Regex.Replace` use `Regex.Match`, then you can use the properties on the `Match` object to figure out where the match occurred.. then the regular string functions (`String.Substring`) can be used to replace the bit you want replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Working sample with named groups:

```
string input = @"<tag abc=""hello world""> abc=whatever</tag>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<(?<Tag>\w+)\s+(?<Attr>\w+)=.*?>.*?</\k<Tag>>");
string output = regex.Replace(input, match => 
{
    var attr = match.Groups["Attr"];
    var value = match.Value;
    var left = value.Substring(0, attr.Index);
    var right = value.Substring(attr.Index + attr.Length);
    return left + attr.Value.Replace("abc", "def") + right;
});
```